# Lock Rotation of Face

Tags: transforms

When I rotate a mesh, I'd like the rotation of one face to stay the same but the rest of the mesh to rotate, is there a way I can lock the rotation of the face? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Hook modifier.

1. Select the face and add it to a new vertex group
2. Add a new empty (position doesn't matter)
3. Add *Hook modifier* to your Object and target the Empty and the vertex group

<sup>This cube has a "Static Face" vertex group containing one face</sup>
[image]

Comment: Tysm! That worked perfectly! :D

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Ha :) I had never think about the use a Hook as stabiliser :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*I don't know what is the purpose, but there can be used other methods can be ...*

---

### Edit Mode

- select all with one face excluded
- if pivot should be object origin - snap Cursor to Origin and switch Pivot Point to 3D Cursor

[image]

Issue can raise in animation, because to animate vertices you will have to use ShapeKeys, and because vertices are transformed on shortest way from one key to another shape is deformed between keyframes.

### Bone

... you can use an armature:

- Add an Armature > Bone
- Select *Mesh*, Shift select *Armature*, *Parent to* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> *Armature With* **Empty Group**
- Select Mesh, switch to Edit mode select all with face vertices excluded and in *Properties editor, > Data tab > Vertex Groups* select newly created *Bone* group and click *Assign* button

[image]

### Hook

... or use a Hook in opposite way as Jachym's answer. He's using it as stabiliser for a face, but you can also revert this by assigning all vertices excluded one face into vertex group. Mesh stay untouched and you will use a Hook (Empty or any other object used as hook) as transformer.